# Browsing/editing RDF/OWL Instances

Tags: browser, editor, instance, rdf, owl

I'm looking for a graphical browser for examining large networks of OWL/RDF instances. Protege's instance browser isn't really useful and if COE supports instance browsing, I've not discovered how. Network size is around a million nodes.

I'm hoping to be able to search for an instance, expand it to show its relationships, and explore other instances from there. Graphical would be nice, but a plain Jtree would do too.

Answer (score 1):

The [Tabulator](http://www.w3.org/2005/ajar/tab) project from the W3C is designed for browsing RDF data sets. It provides an add-in for Firefox, that may facilitate your explorations. it also has features to make your data browsable remotely using AJAX.

Comment: Thanks for the lead. Couldn't make it work on first try but will try again later.

But I'm afraid the firefox-only restriction and browser security problems will rule this out for my application. This is a federal application in which some of the RDF sites are sensitive (not all, but some). Anything that even smells of "a security problem" is knee-jerk fatal in this world.

Research note: making semantic web work in a world with secrets needs thought!! ;)

Comment: Very true, Brad, but I guess no more true than in any other aspect of web development. I guess you're just lucky that in the gov environment there is a will to address issues of security!

Answer (score 0):

The MIT [Simile](http://simile.mit.edu/) project developed a faceted browser for RDF called [Longwell](http://simile.mit.edu/wiki/Longwell). This was a research project. Development has now languished, and their demos seem to be broken; however, I can attest to the fact that it works. I use it regularly to browse an extremely miscellaneous collection of RDF instance data on my local machine.

Longwell is written as a Java web application. It comes with its own jetty server or can be run as a servelet. It can be run in memory, or with a variety of back-ends. It parses both rdf/xml and n3, and is highly configurable via velocity templates, css, and the 'Fresnel' RDF display ontology. It's a pity it hasn't been pursued further; I've found its ui to be very agreeable, and particularly useful is the fact that it will browse any RDF instance data you like, with or without schemas or ontologies.